# How does Timed_mutex work?

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I just get stuck in this code, I assumed that the code locks the global variable "a" for 30 seconds but the output doesn't satisfy this assumption. Could any one help me figure out why this happens and another question is that is there any function to lock required variable for a specific time, being specified by the programmer. Thank you in advanced for your consideration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std;
// std::chrono::seconds interval(100);


timed_mutex test_mutex;
int a = 0;

void * write(void * args)
{
    auto start=std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    test_mutex.try_lock_until(start+std::chrono::seconds(30));
    a = 2;
    cout << "Here is place #" << a << endl;
    test_mutex.unlock();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main()
{
    auto start=std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    pthread_t check;
    pthread_create(&check, NULL, &write, NULL);
    test_mutex.try_lock_until(start+std::chrono::seconds(30));
    a = 1;
    cout << "Here is place #" << a << endl;
    test_mutex.unlock();
    pthread_join(check, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, did you search before asking this? It seems to be clearly documented to me.

Answer (score 0):

`std::timed_mutex::try_lock_until` returns either:

1. `true` when the mutex is acquired, or
2. `false` if it timed out (waited as long as allowed) trying to lock the mutex

Note that this code is buggy anyway, because it doesn't check the return value. So, `a` can be written even if the mutex was *not* acquired.